# How can I process an array variable that hide inside another variable?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

How can i save the $box1 and $box2 in DB and take it out as variable? so that i can loop it.

```
if($m_name[$x]=='a'){ 
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox[][]" (in_array($box1[$i][$j], $autocheck_array) ? ' checked="checked"' : '') . '"/>';
}
elseif($m_name[$x]=='b'){
     echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox[][]" (in_array($box2[$i][$j], $autocheck_array) ? ' checked="checked"' : '') . '"/>';
}
```

`$box1` and `$box2` are row title in DB,so im not able to loop it

Comment: <?php
   $abc[1][2]=1;
   $a="$abc[1][2]";
    echo "$a"; ?>

Comment: Please clarify the question, it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: What do you expect it to do, what is it doing instead? Have you read the section of the PHP manual about variable interpolation in strings?

Comment: Sorry guys, i have asked a wrong question.
Actually the question is.
I will take a string from mysql DB.
after that I explode another variable to array.

So,i need to take the string from DB and combine with array number to build a variable same as the variable i explode.
This is because I want to loop all the variable from DB and not edit it by coding when handle by user.  
Sorry if my English is bad.

Comment: Don't all the solutions still work with that question?

Comment: If not, please update your question, and show what you're talking about in detail.

Comment: Your update is so different, you should delete this and start over. None of the answers make sense with this question.

Comment: ok ..i will update another question..sorry

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes. Array values don't work simply like that inside quotes

```
<?php 
$abc[1][2]=1; 
$a=$abc[1][2]; 
echo $a; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `{}` when interpolating complex variables:

```
$a = "The value of a[1][2] is {$abc[1][2]}.";
```

See the section **Complex (curly) syntax** in the PHP strings [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Note that you only need to do this if you're interpolating as part of a larger string. If you're just trying to assign the array value directly, you don't need to put it in quotes. You can just assign:

```
$a = $abc[1][2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this ?

```
$abc[1][2]=1;
$a=$abc[1][2];
echo $a;// Outputs 1
```

Answer (score 0):

by using this statement `$a="$abc[1][2]";` you are actually assigning `$a` a `string` value

remove the quotes

```
<?php 
$abc[1][2]=1; 
$a=$abc[1][2]; 
echo $a; 
?>
```